# WebSphere MQ Acknowledgement and Reply-To Queue

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

We are sending XML text messages via a remote queue definition CLIENT.DATA (transmit queue, send/recv channels etc.) from our queue manager QM_MINE queue manager QM_CLIENT and queue CLIENT.DATA. The message reaches the destination (CLIENT.DATA queue at the client's). The problem at hand is to able to receive acknowledgement messages (exact copy of the message sent) on a local queue CLIENT.DATA.ACK in QM_MINE as soon as messages reaches CLIENT.DATA in QM_CLIENT *automatically*.

I found couple of resources at WebSphere v7.1 infocenter on [reply-to queue](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.doc/ic10950_.htm) and [message acknowledgement](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.msc.doc/xms_cmesack.html&resultof=%22acknowledgement%22%20%22acknowledg%22%20)  however they were not really helpful to me.

So far I tried to use the reply to queue way. I created a transmit queue QM_MCT on QM.OCC. Every message I send to the CLIENT.DATA queue, I specified the reply-queue using setJMSReplyTo() method. However I am sure that is not it, there is more I am missing.

MQ Objects Summary:

> QM_MINE: CLIENT_DATA (remoteQ), QM_CLIENT (transmitQ), CLIENT_DATA_ACK(localQ)
>
> QM_CLIENT: CLIENT_DATA (localQ), QM_MINE (transmitQ),
>
> And, sender/receiver channels at both ends.

Source Code Fragements:

Client Data Sender (under transaction):

```
public class ClientServiceImpl extends JmsGatewaySupport implements ClientService {

    @Override
    public void sendClientData(String dataXML) {
        getJmsTemplate().convertAndSend(dataXML);
    }
}
```

Message Converter :

```
public Message toMessage(Object o, Session session) throws JMSException, MessageConversionException {
    String dataXML = (String) o;
    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
    message.setJMSReplyTo(replyToQueue);
    message.setText(dataXML);
    return message;
}
```

Note:

Current I don't have any MDP or MDB to listen and consume messages from CLIENT_DATA queue in QM_CLIENT. I merely send it from QM_MINE and it gets moved to QM_CLIENT by MQ. Do I need to consume the messages to get this working?

I use java, JMS , Spring and WebShere MQ v7.1 on Linux. Any more information will be provided upon request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the section on the [`MQMD.Report`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzak.doc/fr13320_.htm) field.  Yes, you do need to set the reply-to fields so that the acknowledgement can find its way back to you.  However you also need to tell WMQ that you want it to generate the report message.  For what you want, set the field to `MQRO_COA_WITH_FULL_DATA`.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I got it working by adding the line "message.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_REPORT_COA, MQC.MQRO_COA_WITH_FULL_DATA);" just before "message.setText(..)". However in QM_CLIENT I had to create a remote queue def for CLIENT_DATA_ACK (along with the transmit queue for QM_MINE). Is this how it is supposed to be? Is it possible to do this without creating the remote queue def in QM_CLIENT?

Comment: `QM_CLIENT` needs to be able to resolve a route back to `QM_MINE`.  If there's an XMitQ named `QM_MINE` defined on `QM_CLIENT` the messages should get back.  Lacking that, a QRemote named `QM_MINE` defined on `QM_CLIENT` specifying the actual XMitQ name (and no `RNAME` or `RQMNAME` entries) would do the trick.

Comment: I want to do this without the RemoteQ DATA.CLIENT.ACK on QM_CLIENT, so I removed that and kept only the XMITQ QM_MINE in QM_CLIENT, however the replyTo messages get accumulated in QM_MINE. replyTo queue name is DATA.CLIENT.ACK (which is on QM_MINE not QM_CLIENT). Still something amiss.

Comment: There *is* a channel serving that XMitQ back to QM_MINE, right?  Do other messages addressed to QM_MINE get back OK?  Is the channel running? In retry?  Stopped?

Comment: There was a mistake on the channel, it is corrected now it works with just the XMITQ pointing back; Nice. Thanks!!

Comment: What is the maximum size of correlation ID I can use? Perhaps I can getaway from MQRO_COA_WITH_FULL_DATA buy using MQRO_COA, I think this makes sense as opposed to ending the whole XML back, since I am  interested in three fields. Are there any other attributes I can use in Header for this purpose?

Comment: At the link above are all the report options.  You can request just the header, the header with the first 200 bytes or the whole message.