# How to setup confirmation of arrival (COA) in JMS using Spring?

Tags: spring-jms

I am using the library https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring/ and can't find a way of getting confirmation of arrival when I put a message in the queue. Most documentation I find about the library is for basic examples.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "confirmation of arrival"? That is implied by not getting an exception when sending to JMS.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a Spring question, though you do have to setup how the MQ message is created. See [WebSphere MQ Acknowledgement and Reply-To Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503727/websphere-mq-acknowledgement-and-reply-to-queue)